# TSQL Function The multi-part identifier "" could not be bound

Tags: t-sql

I have a function which is a simple case statement, however when i attempt to execute this function i get the error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "EXTRAS.FindCustomerfromCostCentre" could not be bound.

My Function is very simple...

```
Alter FUNCTION [EXTRAS].[FindCustomerfromCostCentre] 

(
    @CostCentre Varchar
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

return  
case 
    when SUBSTRING(@CostCentre,3,3) = '401' Then '7010'
    when SUBSTRING(@CostCentre,3,3) = '402' Then '7020'
    when SUBSTRING(@CostCentre,3,3) = '403' Then '7030'
    when SUBSTRING(@CostCentre,3,3) = '407' Then '7070'
    when SUBSTRING(@CostCentre,3,3) = '409' Then '7090'
    when SUBSTRING(@CostCentre,3,3) = '414' Then '7140'
    when SUBSTRING(@CostCentre,3,3) = '416' Then '7160'
    Else '0'
end 
END
```

When i execute i am calling as such

```
SELECT  [EXTRAS].[FindCustomerfromCostCentre] CostCentre_Code

FROM dbo.COSTCENTRE

Where STATUS = 'Active'
```

Any Tips on why i am getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parenthesis around the parameter

```
SELECT  [EXTRAS].[FindCustomerfromCostCentre](CostCentre_Code)

FROM dbo.COSTCENTRE

Where STATUS = 'Active'
```

You also need to specify the length of your parameter in the declaration for the function.

```
(
    @CostCentre Varchar
)
```

Not doing that will give you a `varchar(1)`.

```
(
    @CostCentre Varchar(1)
)
```